# protractorjs e2e test, fake/set time of day

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, protractor

Say I have a time sensitive app, such as a football game betting app, and I can not best after the game has started.  Now I want some angularjs, protractorjs e2e tests for the app that run on something like Jenkins. The issue is I don't know when the app is run as that is based on people updated the repo'. So how can I fake or set the time, or an I looking at this wrong?

I had looked all online but can't see a say of getting protractorjs to set the time of day for the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if protractor can change the time on your computer or anything, but there are still some ways to work with it.

You should probably be looking into a mock mode version of your website that your protractor tests can hit. Using ngMockE2E (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E) and other mock tools, you can, for example, mock the service that gets the time for your website. You should have an angular service that checks for the time of day and then feeds that data through to your site to enable or disable betting. You can mock the service and feed it different sets of time, maybe attach those to different routes on your mock mode, and have your protractor tests hit that.

Let me know if this sounds like what you need, and we can get more into it.

Comment: Yeah, abstract to a service and then mock. That's the angular way.

Comment: Thanks. I am battling with ngMockE2E ($httpbackend) now and will try to moch the service.  Don't know how to do that yet but I will try and figure it out. I was hoping to to mock the service but, hay, like @Sulthan said its the Angular way.